# Who owns this abandoned airplane?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-ownership

I am trying to buy an abandoned aircraft on my airfield in France. The problem is, since 2012, the aircraft is abandoned in French government Hangars.

The Beechcraft Duke is de-registered since 2012 and has never been registered since now on. The owner vanished, nobody knows if he is still alive. I have been in contact with the FAA, apparently he never answered of the letters the have send him.

My questions are: who is the owner of this aircraft at this precise moment? Is it an abandoned aircraft? No owner? No registration? What is the administrative status?

Here is more information about the aircraft:

- Manufacturer: Beech
- Model:    B-60 Duke    Search all Beech B-60
- Year built:   1975
- Construction Number (C/N):    P-367
- Aircraft Type:    Fixed wing multi engine
- Number of Seats:  6
- Number of Engines:    2
- Engine Type:  Reciprocating
- Engine Manufacturer and Model:    Lycoming TIO-541-E1C4
- Also Registered As:   G-DUKE
- De-registered  Cancel: 1982-02-10
- Aircraft Registration Number: N6779S
- Mode S (ICAO24) Code: A8F95D
- Certification Class:  Standard
- Certification Issued: 1985-08-23
- Air Worthiness Test:  1982-03-03
- Last Action Taken:    1993-04-24
- Current Status:   Undel Tri Owner
- Registration Type:    Individual
- Address:  Portland, OR 97210 United States
- Region:   Northwest Mountain

Comment: The question of who is the owner is a legal matter, not an aviation one.  Whether you can get it certified for flight is another matter, but perhaps best to sort out the first issue first.

Comment: [According to flightaware](https://de.flightaware.com/live/flight/N6779S) this aircraft flew in New York State in 2018. There must be a mixup somewhere?

Comment: maybe the registration N6779S has been given to another aircraft. since it has been deregistered in 2012, the registration doesn't belong to the duke anymore?

Comment: so I need to get in touch With M.Posnansky...?

Comment: It [doesn't appear that N6779S has been reassigned](https://registry.faa.gov/AircraftInquiry/Search/NNumberResult?nNumberTxt=6779S). But it could be a mixup somewhere else in the system.

Comment: The owner appears to be the same as the (shared) owner, designer and builder of [N15PF](https://registry.faa.gov/AircraftInquiry/Search/NNumberResult?nNumberTxt=15PF), which has [a Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posnansky/Fronius_PF-1_White_Knight). This registration is active and also lists another owner who you might be able to contact.

Comment: The mailing address for Fronius is literally on the FAA registration. But you should probably just hire a private investigator who can make contact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last registered owner of the aircraft is Mr. Hernan Posnansky. Since he seems to be alive and well, you should make him an offer for it.

Comment: Hello M.Jimenez, thank you for your answer. I think I'll have to find one his daughter and asked her to give me the aircraft. I am sure she doesn't even know that her father had a duke abandonned in LFGB. let's try to find Mme.Posnansky ... if her name is still the same.

Comment: He may also be alive but in a care home or otherwise unable to react to any of this. Many possibilities.

Comment: It's been 1 week now I am trying to find his daughter. I found on facebook his first wife and her son, I wrote them a message but no answers. So I tried to find his second wife who used to live in Zurich, close to where I live. Without success for the moment. I think it would be easier to work with a detective at this point.

Comment: No, it would be easier to hire an attorney with experience in French aviation law and abandoned aircraft. The attorney can advise you as to the law and then take whatever actions are required. A detective may not find anyone and that's all they can do.

Answer (score 8):

My husband’s last communication with Hernan Posnansky was sometimes in September 2021 and at that time he was in Zurich and seeking contact with a faculty member of the Technical University. No contact since that time. Hernan’s age will be roughly 78.

To the best of our knowledge he was only married once.

Sharon de Piolenc

Answer (score 6):

Fyi, Mr Posnansky is alive and well and has just rejoined our EAA Chapter, [www.EAA240.org](http://www.EAA240.org) today, July 8 2023.

Comment: Hello!  Would you have the chance to ask him if he’s ok to have chat with me ? E-mail? Phone number? Anything !